# Is it normal to have "security.securehw.available" and "security.securevm.avaiable" false on Samsung Galaxy S20?

Tags: samsung, build.prop

I have a Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G. I'm using [Android System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arumcomm.systeminfo) app to see how the system is running, and in the app, I see that I don't have HW and VM security policy.

It's written `security.securehw.available(false)` and `security.securevm.avaiable(false)`, and I also have `ro.build.keys(test key)`. I think this configuration is not normal and the phone has been modified

Is it normal?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking for. Please edit your question and describe in detail what you did. When it comes to specific apps please always state the full name, packageName and best the link to the app in Google Play Store.

Comment: The app is android system info https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arumcomm.systeminfo irs an app to see all how the system is running and in the app i see that i dont have hw and vm security policy its written security.securehw.available(false) and security.securevm.avaiable(false) also i have ro.build.keys(test key) i think this configuration is not normal and the phone has bieen modified